# How can commutativity of operators be assumed in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Below is a screenshot from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right.  Note that V is a vector space over $F$, which is either equal to $R$ or $C$.  I haven't reached the chapter on commutating operators yet and thus far, this text has been very transparent about using results not covered in the book that are used, ex. stating that some analysis is needed for a more illuminating proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, and that De Moivre's Theorem would be a "given".  So, the assertion that about commutativity make me feel like I'm missing something really obvious, even though the last time commutativity was even mentioned in this text, it was to explain that linear maps are not necessarily commutative.  I appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: $p(T) q(T) = q(T) p(T)$ for polynomials $p, q$. See 5.17 of LADR.

Comment: Ah.  So my misconception was thinking those terms were merely operators, instead of polynomials with operators plugged in, so to speak.  Thank you.

Comment: More directly, any operator commutes with the identity operator, so any linear combinations of $T$ and $I$ commute with any other linear combination of $T$ and $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that, in general, for any two linear maps $S, T$, it is not necessarily the case that $S$ and $T$ commute, i.e. it is possible to have $ST$ be a different linear map than $TS$.

However, in this proof, they are saying that two specific linear maps, $T-\lambda_j I$ and $T-\lambda_k I$, happen to commute. We can see these linear maps commute using the distributive property and commutativity of scalar addition and multiplication:
$$
\begin{align*}
(T-\lambda_j I)(T-\lambda_k I) &=T(T-\lambda_k I)-\lambda_j(T-\lambda_k I) \\ &=T^2-\lambda_k T-\lambda_j T+\lambda_j\lambda_k I \\ &=T^2-(\lambda_j+\lambda_k)T+\lambda_j\lambda_k
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
(T-\lambda_k I)(T-\lambda_j I) &=T(T-\lambda_j I)-\lambda_k(T-\lambda_j I) \\ &=T^2-\lambda_j T-\lambda_k T+\lambda_k\lambda_j I \\ &=T^2-(\lambda_j+\lambda_k)T+\lambda_j\lambda_k
\end{align*}
$$
As you can see, we have $(T-\lambda_j I)(T-\lambda_k I)=T^2-(\lambda_j+\lambda_k)T+\lambda_j\lambda_k=(T-\lambda_k I)(T-\lambda_j I)$, which suffices to show commutativity for these two specific linear operators.